# Probability, Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability

Every week a family visits their favourite restaurant. The restaurant has
15 tables, and on each visit the family is seated at a table chosen uniformly
at random, with all choices being independent. Show that the probability
is at least 1/2 that the family will sit at every table in the restaurant over
the course of a year.

Comment: What have you tried? (Or I will close this question.)

Comment: I am just not sure what is the right thing to do

Comment: I know the birthday problem, but that's to share the 2 outcomes instead of covering all outcomes

Answer (score 2):

This is the coupon collector's problem with $n=15$ coupons. [There is a bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Tail_estimates) on the probability that not all coupons are obtained after some multiple of $n\log n$ tries (weeks in this case):
$$P(T>kn\log n)\le n^{1-k}$$
If we set $k=1.27$ we get for this problem
$$P(T>51.588\dots)=P(T\ge52)\le0.481\dots<\frac12$$
which immediately proves the claim.